# Dart: create multiple objects at once

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I create multiple objects in 1 Step in Dart? Something like:

```
Class Player{ 

var Health;
var Level; .... }
```

Somewhere else:

```
Player[] player = new Player[20];
```

How can I do that in Dart?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a list of `Player` using the following line:

```
     List<Player> player = new List(20);
```

And then initialize each object of your `player` list :

```
     for (var i in jsonResponse['participants']) {
       player[x] = new Player() ; // add this to your code
       var fill = player[x];
       fill.health = i['health'];
       x++;
     }
```

You can find more information about the proper way of building and initializing `list` in the official Dart [Documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: When I try it on that way I get: Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'profileIconId=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: level=1301) when I loop over the list of Objects and try to fill in values

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna create a lot "Players"... Try this:

```dart
var players = List.generate(20, (i) => Player(/* properties */));
```

Filling in from any source, you can use the "i" as the index.

```dart
var players = List.generate(20, (i) { 
    var sourceRef = source[i];

    return Player(
      health: sourceRef["health"]
    ); 
});
```

Comment: How can I fill in all values for the specific player on your way?